# If working but not else if

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The 'if' scenario works but the else if does not. I am trying to toggle the images on the click of class="show-real-pixels"

```
<div class="image not-hidden">
      <img src="img/healthyout/WF-onboard.png">
</div>

<div class="image hidden">
      <img src="img/healthyout/HF-onboard.png">
</div>

<div class="btn pull-right show-real-pixels">show real pixels</div>  


$(".show-real-pixels").click(
      function () {

       if ($(".image").hasClass("hidden")) {
          $(".image").removeClass("hidden").addClass("not-hidden");
        }  
        else if ($(".image").hasClass("not-hidden")) {
          $(".image").removeClass("not-hidden").addClass("hidden");
        }
});
```

Comment: Post the code or provide a jsfiddle

Comment: one class is enough to differentiate elements, why do you use two?

Comment: Make a fiddle for this, with complete code(HTML and css), this tells nothing.

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/gKayF/.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tWLkX/4/ The fiddle, bro

Comment: @FelixKling you have both images shown, I only want one image shown at a time

Comment: Ah, why didn't you say that? In that case, you have to apply the `.addClass`, `.removeClass` calls to a single element, not to all the images. Or use `.toggleClass` as shown in the answers. Always explain your problem properly! "The else if is not working" is not a good problem description, because it clearly works (it gets executed). It just doesn't work like you want it to and in the case you have to tell us what you want!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) instead of if else

```
$(".image").toggleClass("hidden not-hidden");
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `.toggleClass` like

```
$(".show-real-pixels").click(function () {

      $(".image").toggleClass("hidden not-hidden");
});
```

See this [**LINK**](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Comment: +1 one from me.... may be the total rep has something to do with it

Comment: Haha ...You won the race man.

Answer (score 0):

Try this i code for only your second image toggling and for that i removed your first div not-hidden class. It is much easier for you because you already wrote these lines then you have to change only few things:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".show-real-pixels").click(function () {
            var hidn = $(".image").hasClass("hidden");
            var hidnt = $(".image").hasClass("not-hidden");
            if (hidn) {
                $(".hidden").removeClass("hidden").addClass("not-hidden");
            } else if (hidnt) {
                $(".not-hidden").removeClass("not-hidden").addClass("hidden");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: That's equivalent to what the OP already has, which is not what they want.

Comment: (1) You might want to *explicitly* explain what you have changed. (2) Please don't format normal text as code. It makes your answer difficult to read. (3) Don't use terms like "simplest ever". As you can see in the other answers, the one-line `$(".image").toggleClass("hidden not-hidden");` is much simpler than your 8-line solution.

Comment: But brother user already wrote 8 line then only need to add some small changes. And other thing i will keep it in my mind for next time okay...

Comment: So you mean "simplest" as in fewest changes, ok. Again: Don't format your text as code! Why are you doing that? No one wants to scroll right just to read the text.